# How to split currently used partition on Ubuntu server?

Tags: server, partitioning, mount

I would like to split a currently used partition that is mounted to `/usr` directory. I did this because / only had 1 gb of data allocated to it. Now, I did not account for the /home directory when I made this partition (or I would have made two partitions). So I have 14 gb mounted to usr/ with 12 gb free. Is there a way I can reclaim the free space on this partition to make another partition to mount to /home?

Here is the result of a `df -h`:

[image]

I have tried to split the `/dev/mmcblk1p4` into 2 different partitions but I was not able to save the partition table correctly.

Comment: post the screenshot of your gparted partition editor.

Comment: Is this a server install (command-line), or a desktop install (graphical interface)?

Comment: This is server install, sorry I should have specified. No GUI.

Comment: Edit your question with the output of `sudo parted -l` please.

Answer (score 1):

You can download [gParted Live CD](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) which is capable of resizing partitions:

[image]

Note that `gparted` cannot safely resize actively mounted partitions, so you will need to do this from a LiveCD.

Comment: `gparted` can't safely resize an actively mounted partition I don't think, and it looks like their `/usr` is mounted there.  We'll need to see what their actual partition table layout is once they post a screenshot of `gparted` as it shows on their screen.

Comment: Ok, I updated the answer :) Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: For those of us who don't audit all the edits, it looks to others like no changes were made.  I added a (clearly visible!) notice that `gparted` can't safely resize active partitions, and that this will need to be done from a LiveCD.  Note that the `server` tag on this question makes me think this still doesn't answer the question, `gparted` requires a GUI.